# ImageIcon not displaying (default path?)

Tags: java, imageicon

In this Java code - it first looks in 'resources' folder, correct?
I've tried adding '/' and 'resources/' to the beginning of the path - but can't get image to display. My 'resources' folder is parallel to my 'java' folder as far as hiearchy.

```
src
 |-main
    |-resources
    |    |-graphics
    |    |-sounds
    |-java
```

```
private void loadImages() {
        ghost = new ImageIcon("graphics/ghost.png").getImage();

@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
```

Comment: It looks for a subdirectory named `graphics` below the working directory. The working directory is the value returned by `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: Using AndroidStudio - do I integrate that into my code or run it from somewhere else?
(fairly new at this). How do I define my working directory?

Comment: Are you writing an Android app?

Comment: Not at the moment, just playing around in Java.

Comment: Use the `getResource(...)` method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why NOT to use ImageIcon method? I see it used it a lot of example code...

Comment: Because ImageIcon takes a file name.  You are passing a relative file name, which means it is dependent on the current directory of the process, which is in no way guaranteed.  getResource does not depend on the current directory at all.  Also, if you ever package your application as a .jar, the ImageIcon constructor will fail, because a .jar entry is not a separate file at all, just a sequence of compressed bytes within the .jar file.